# How to get multiple selected rows in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I am having an issue with `selarrrow` function (it returns null) - is there an alternative way to retrieve row ids when several rows are selected?

PS: I am not interested in debugging jqGrid, I just need to retrieve selected row ids.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onSelectAll` event fires when multiselect option is true and you click on the header checkbox. It has attributes : aRowids,status
aRowids array of the selected rows (rowid's).
status - boolean variable determining the status of the header check box - true if checked, false if not checked.
Note that the aRowids always contain the ids when header checkbox is checked or unchecked.
Lastly you  can make your own custom array on every select by following code. Note the key which is set to true will be the id.

```
var rowid = $(this).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id")
```